# Webpack output files to different directories

Tags: webpack

After building a project, I have index.html, bundle.js and some .css files, I would like them to be placed in a dir structure like this:

```
dist/
    - css/all.my.css
    - js/bundle.js
    - index.html
```

Here is what I did for the .js and .css:

```js
entry: {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/src/index.js'),
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'css'),
    filename: '../js/[name].js'
},
```

Here are the corresponding module config:

```js
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
    },
    {
      test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
      loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
    },
    {
      test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
      loader: "file-loader"
    }]
},
```

I have no idea how to copy `index.html` from a folder and put it under dist/. I know `file-loader` is needed but what should I write under `entry` and `output`?

Thanks!

---

I figured it out and here is the solution:

```
output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),   // this is the output directory, everything will be placed under here
        filename: 'js/bundle.js', // move the bundle.js file under the js/ folder, the dir structure will be like this /dist/js/bundle.js
}
```

To move the css file under `dist/css/`:

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!cssnext-loader')
     }]
}
```

I used the ExtractTextPlugin, so to config the output path of the css file, I had to define it in the `plugins` section:

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('./css/bundle.css'), // bundle.css will be put under /dist/css/
]
```

To move images and fonts to their own folder:

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&name=img/[name].[ext]'
    }, {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
    }]
}
```

Pay attention to how the `loader` string is defined: `&name=img/[name].[ext]` means using the original file's name and extension and put it under the img/ folder. Same goes with the font files.

Here is the complete config file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
    path = require('path'),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
    Clean = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: {
        app: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/index.js'),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        filename: 'js/bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/static/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0,plugins[]=transform-decorators-legacy'],
            include: path.join(__dirname, '../app'),
        },{
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!cssnext-loader')
        },{
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
        },{
            test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&name=img/[name].[ext]'
        }]
    },
    cssnext: {
        browsers: 'last 2 versions'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    plugins: [
        new Clean([path.join(__dirname, '../dist')], {
            root: path.join(__dirname, '..'),
            verbose: true
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('./css/bundle.css', {allChunks: true}),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, [/moment$/]), //ignore locale files from moment.js, saves 300k
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            },
            '__DEVTOOLS__': false
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compressor: {
                warnings: false
            },
            mangle: false
        })
    ]
}
```

You won't need all of the stuff in there, I just want to show the big picture what it looks like with everything in place. Only pay attention to the `output`, `loaders` and `plugins`

Comment: These setting won't work, the question is old, because webpack has fundamental changes in webpack 4.0!

Comment: @Ebrahim the solution worked for me just fine in Webpack 4.0.

Answer (score 9):

I think it might be good idea to use this **npm package**

https://github.com/gregnb/filemanager-webpack-plugin

and then use something like this in your webpack config file to move compiled application files to where ever you need.

```
new FileManagerPlugin({
    onEnd: {
        move: [
            {source: 'dist/index.html', destination: '../api/modules/web/views/init-build.phtml'},
            {source: 'dist/js', destination: '../api/public/js'},
            {source: 'dist/images', destination: '../api/public/images'}
        ]
    }
})
```

For example code above moves compiled ng5 application into modular Falcon php application, and makes SPA index file a view. So Falcon might use it to render SPA seed.